# SQL Counting non numeric values from a column

Tags: sql

I have a table named tasks inside is

```
id
tasks
tasks_status
task_date
```

The tasks statuses are "done","pending","forwarded","cancelled".

How can I query the table of counting all the done, all the pending, all the forwarded and all cancelled.

I tried doing all the tweaks from COUNT but to no avail. It's been 2 hours of looking for a way. Please help

My goal is to specifically count only those DONE, I can get the count of all the specifics but just would need to show the total count of done (for example)

Comment: i know it might be easy but please enlighten me guys

Comment: `select tasks_status, count(*) from tasks group by tasks_status` - this should do

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data _and the expected result_ - all as formatted text (no images, no links.) I.e. a [mcve]. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @gaborsch, missing comma.

Comment: hello gaborsch, the problem is, i have multiple types of tasks, id like to differentiate them and my expected result is for example, the total that are done, pending, and etc

Comment: Macy Creed, that's why you should provide a [mcve], to make it easy for us to understand what you want.

Comment: @MacyCreed then perhaps specify the expected result in tabular format. But try this first, maybe this is good enough

Comment: apologies if my question seemed broad but please check my edit again for clarification guys, thank you so much for the help

Comment: Sample table data and expected result is still missing. You've got some answers already anyway, do they solve your problem? If not, things aren't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Group by is better but if you just want the ones specified as 'Done' the below should work.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TASTS WHERE TASKS_STATUS='done'
```

Answer (score 0):

Select what you want with count and Group Them.

```
SELECTS tasks_status, count(tasks_status) FROM status GROUP BY tasks_status;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select tasks_status, count(*) from tasks group by tasks_status
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1e27e/4/0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all counts then you need to use group by but if you want to get count of just one item then group by is not required.

Following is query to generate scenario

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tasks](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [tasks] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [tasks_status] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [task_date] [date] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tasks] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tasks] ([id], [tasks], [tasks_status], [task_date]) VALUES (1, N'task1', N'pending', CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tasks] ([id], [tasks], [tasks_status], [task_date]) VALUES (2, N'task2', N'forwarded', CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tasks] ([id], [tasks], [tasks_status], [task_date]) VALUES (3, N'task3', N'pending', CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tasks] ([id], [tasks], [tasks_status], [task_date]) VALUES (4, N'task4', N'done', CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tasks] ([id], [tasks], [tasks_status], [task_date]) VALUES (5, N'task5', N'done', CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tasks] ([id], [tasks], [tasks_status], [task_date]) VALUES (6, N'task6', N'cancelled', CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tasks] ([id], [tasks], [tasks_status], [task_date]) VALUES (7, N'task7', N'done', CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tasks] ([id], [tasks], [tasks_status], [task_date]) VALUES (8, N'task8', N'forwarded', CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tasks] ([id], [tasks], [tasks_status], [task_date]) VALUES (9, N'task9', N'pending', CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tasks] ([id], [tasks], [tasks_status], [task_date]) VALUES (10, N'task10', N'done', CAST(N'2022-09-30' AS Date))
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tasks] OFF
GO
```

You can use group by if you want to get count of all unique tasks_status or some of tasks_status using following query

For All

```
SELECT tasks_status, count(tasks_status) FROM dbo.tasks GROUP BY tasks_status;
```

For done and pending

```
SELECT tasks_status, count(tasks_status) FROM dbo.tasks 
WHERE tasks_status IN ('done','pending')
GROUP BY tasks_status
```

if you want to get count for done only then you can use either of the following. Use group by if you want to use other columns in select, else if you want to get just count and no other column then just 2nd query without group by

```
SELECT tasks_status, count(tasks_status) FROM dbo.tasks 
WHERE tasks_status =  'done'
GROUP BY tasks_status
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(tasks_status) FROM dbo.tasks WHERE tasks_status='done'
```